# Azure Function (Manual Trigger): Issuing post request

Tags: javascript, azure, http, post, azure-functions

I am trying to issue a post request in javascript using Azure Function (manual trigger) but I am receiving the following error:

```
mscorlib: One or more errors occurred. Error: Cannot find module 'xmlhttprequest'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

Here is my function:

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

module.exports = function (context, input) {
    context.log('The Request body is:', input);
    context.done();

    var url = "<myurl>";


    xhr.open("POST", url, false);

    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    xhr.send(input);
};
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Sorry for the delay of response, you solved the new error?

Comment: Still hitting the following error. Any ideas? mscorlib: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'D:\Windows\system32\.node-xmlhttprequest-sync-7048' at Error (native) at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:641:18) at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:1347:33) at send (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\xmlhttprequest\lib\XMLHttpRequest.js:477:10) – Kevin Ngo 6 secs ago    edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install `xmlhttprequest` module first.

If you are running it in portal, go to `https://{yourfunctionappname}.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`

In the cmd console, input `cd ./site/wwwroot`,
then `npm install xmlhttprequest`.

If you are developing locally, just open a cmd in your function project folder and `npm install xmlhttprequest`.

For this error

> mscorlib: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'D:\Windows\system32\ .node-xmlhttprequest-sync-7048' at Error (native) at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:641:18) at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:1347:33) at send (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\xmlhttprequest\lib\XMLHttpRequest.js:477:10)

You set `open` method asynchronous mode to `false`, which means this method is executed synchronously.

It will create file in process current working directory(cwd). In azure function,it is `D:\Windows\system32` by default, where we have no access to create file due to [Sand box limitation](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#system-drive-access).

If your function runtime version is beta, we can change cwd to function folder by using `process.chdir("d:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\functionname")`. And everything should work.

If runtime is ~1, after cwd changed, new error will occur--the sync lock `.node-xmlhttprequest-sync-xxxx` file can't be removed as expected. So after one execution, function will be blocked next time and fail to respond.

Alternative is to use asynchronous mode or try to use module other than `xmlhttprequest`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `HTTP` module of NodeJS - https://nodejs.org/api/http.html

In that scenario you would start with:

```
var http = require('http');
```

and then send data with:

```
var req = http.request(options, function(response) {
      var str = "";
      response.on("data", function (chunk) {
        str += chunk;
      });

      response.on("end", function () {
        res.json(str);           
      });          
    });
```